# What other ways are there to discover non-Chinese trending repos on GitHub?

Tags: github

One of my favorite things to do is browse [Github Trending](https://github.com/trending) for inspiration, however, there has been an uptick in Chinese language repos dominating the Trending page. I am all for inclusivity, but as I do not understand Chinese,  I don't see more relevant repos I might otherwise had since the results are limited to 25.

What other methods are available for discovery of popular/trending repos? 
Is there a search method to filter English *language* repos? Or possibly a method to omit repos that have a majority of non-latin characters in the readme?

I did reach out to Github support and they acknowledged my question, but said there is no effort to filter by *language*, and that my request would be passed on for consideration.

For now I am making use of the *code language* filter on the right to view a little bit more, as well as the explore feature, which is based on starred repos and similar, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I created a [tampermonkey script](https://github.com/miao1007/github-trending-filter) which removes project by personal keywords/regexp in github-trending, however, it's just a client side filter.

Answer (score 0):

I think GITHUB now has a option to search based on language. I don't how long they have this support, but I only know about this today.

https://github.com/trending?spoken_language_code=en

You can change the language in Trending page.